# How to return this array index for selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I make alert() return either 123, 456 or the nth group key?

I wanna retrieve the index key is to do some chain operations on the corresponding option values.

Note: The index keys could just as well be alphanumeric.

HTML:

```
<select name="option[group][123]">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
<select name="option[value][123]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select name="option[group][456]">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
<select name="option[value][456]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
$("select[name^='option[group]']").change(function(){
  alert('Index:' + $(this).fieldsetIndexKeyIdentifier());
  // Do something with option values of group
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `.index()`?

Comment: Since .index() is not the thing. I could just as well state .dummy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it out of the name attribute like this:

```
$("select[name^='option[group]']").change(function(){
    var nums = this.name.match(/\[(\d+)\]$/)
    if (nums) {
        alert('Index:' + nums[1]);
    }
  // Do something with option values of group
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TcRzW/

Or, if you want any sequence of characters from the last index in the name, it would be this:

```
$("select[name^='option[group]']").change(function(){
    var nums = this.name.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]$/)
    if (nums) {
        alert('Index:' + nums[1]);
    }
  // Do something with option values of group
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TcRzW/

If you now want to know which group number you're working on, you can do that like this:

```
var selectGroups$ = $("select[name^='option[group]']");
selectGroups$.change(function(){
    var index = selectGroups$.index(this);
    // index will be a number like 0, 1, 2, 3 for which
    // sequential "select[name^='option[group]']" we are operating on.
});
```

Comment: That would only work for numeric index keys. Is there no conventional way of doing this? Like $(this).parent.something(...)

Comment: @tim: I don't speak for jfriend00, but IMO, the conventional way is to be a programmer, and write a little code that does what you need.

Comment: @tim - the data is ONLY available inside the name string.  As far as the browser is concerned the name is just a string.  The [xxx] is a convention in the name that gets used by other parts of the process.  If you want to parse out whatever is in the last [] in the name, then the regex can be change to take any sequence of characters.  I've added that option to my answer too.

Comment: Is it smarter to get the nth key index rather than the key index name? I later need to pass this on to the corresponding group of option value.

Comment: I don't know what "nth key index" is.  Are you now asking a different question?  If so, please explain what that is.  If you're trying to find which group number sequentially on the page you're in, I've added that as a third option to my answer.

Comment: @Tim - I don't have enough context to know what is the best item to pass around.  I would generally use classes, ids and containers to identify which form items are which and then you could get the one you wanted easily by getting its identifiers.

Answer (score -1):

This does not directly answer the question but I accomplished chained select fields like this:

```
$("select[name^='option[group]']").change(function(){
    var valueField = this.name.replace(/group/, 'value');
    $("select[name='"+ valueField +"']").somefunction(...);
});
```